# How to make change of variables in animation.Funcanimation function in Python?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am actually working on a Python Project where I need to animate variations over time of a concentration, to do so I need the values of my concentration at time t-1 to calculate the concentration at time t.

I would like the "animate" function to use the new values of n0 and n1 when being called. Presently it only uses the same values of n0 and n1 as I declared them in my initial conditions and do not take into account the changes it makes to n0 and n1 during the first plot.

Here is a sample of my code (K, L and M are constant floats):

```
# Initial conditions

n0 = f(X)
n1 = n0.copy()

n1[1:-1] = K * (n0[0:-2] - 2 * n0[1:-1] + n0[2:]) - L * (n0[2:] - n0[:-2]) + M * n0[1:-1]
n0 = n1.copy()

# Animation


fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes(xlim=(-0.5, 1.3), ylim=(min(f(X)), max(f(X))), xlabel="x", ylabel="n", title="n en fonction de x")
line, = ax.plot([], [], lw=2)
time_text = ax.text(0.02, 0.95, '', transform=ax.transAxes)

def init():
    time_text.set_text('')
    line.set_data([],[])
    return line, time_text

def animate(i,n0,n1):
    n1[1:-1] = K * (n0[0:-2] - 2 * n0[1:-1] + n0[2:]) - L * (n0[2:] - n0[:-2]) + M * n0[1:-1]
    n0 = n1.copy()
    t = i * dt
    time_text.set_text('time = %f ms' % (t * 1000))
    y = n1
    line.set_data(X, y)
    return line, time_text


ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, init_func=init, frames=nt, blit=True, interval=1, repeat=False, fargs=(n0, n1))

plt.show()
```

Hope you can help me because I am a new user of animation.Funcanimation and I do not understand everything about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A rather crude way to achieve the desired result is to use global variable

```
Fmin2 = 0
Fmin1 = 1

fig,ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(4,4))
ax.set_xlim(0,200)
ax.set_ylim(0,200)
line, = ax.plot([], [], 'ro')
time_text = ax.text(0.02, 0.95, '', transform=ax.transAxes)

def init():
    global Fmin2,Fmin1
    Fmin2 = 0
    Fmin1 = 1
    time_text.set_text('')
    line.set_data([],[])
    return line, time_text

def animate(i):
    global Fmin2,Fmin1
    Fn = Fmin1+Fmin2
    Fmin2 = Fmin1
    Fmin1 = Fn
    time_text.set_text('i={:d}'.format(i))
    line.set_data([Fmin1],[Fn])
    return line, time_text


ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, init_func=init, frames=10, blit=True)
plt.show()
```

[image]

A cleaner way would be to integrate your animation in a class, and have n0 and n1 be members of that class that are updated in the `animate(self, i)` function.

Comment: Thank you very much, it works as expected ! But you are right, it seems a bit crude... I will try look into creating a class as you say.